# How to get JS tab selector to not scroll

Tags: javascript, tabs

I'm using this JS for tabs. However, it continually makes the selected tab box scroll to the top of the page when clicked.

I can't figure out what part of it is doing that and am trying to get rid of it. Essentially I just want it to function as a normal tab clicker without causing the entire page to scroll.

Any help?

I added a snippet with a large top margin so you can see what happens when you click the tab. I just want those boxes to change without the page physically scrolling to them on its own.

```js
'use strict';

function Tabs() {
  var bindAll = function() {
    var menuElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab]');
    for (var i = 0; i < menuElements.length; i++) {
      menuElements[i].addEventListener('click', change, false);
    }
  }

  var clear = function() {
    var menuElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab]');
    for (var i = 0; i < menuElements.length; i++) {
      menuElements[i].classList.remove('active');
      var id = menuElements[i].getAttribute('data-tab');
      document.getElementById(id).classList.remove('active');
    }
  }

  var change = function(e) {
    clear();
    e.target.classList.add('active');
    var id = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-tab');
    document.getElementById(id).classList.add('active');
  }

  bindAll();
}

var connectTabs = new Tabs();
```

```css
.b-box {margin-top: 1500px;}

.b-tab {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: none
}

.b-tab.active {
  display: block;
}

.b-nav-tab {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.b-nav-tab.active {
  color: #ff4200;
}
```

```html
<a href="#orange" data-tab="orange" class="b-nav-tab active">
  Orange
</a>
<a href="#green" data-tab="green" class="b-nav-tab">
  Green
</a>
<a href="#blue" data-tab="blue" class="b-nav-tab">
  Blue
</a>

<div class="b-box">
<div id="orange" class="b-tab active">
  Orange tab content
</div>
<div id="green" class="b-tab">
  Green tab content
</div>
<div id="blue" class="b-tab">
  Blue tab content
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your code.
Actually you was showing # sign in href so it redirect the position to that box. I removed it.

Good Luck.

```js
'use strict';

function Tabs() {
  var bindAll = function() {
    var menuElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab]');
    for (var i = 0; i < menuElements.length; i++) {
      menuElements[i].addEventListener('click', change, false);
    }
  }

  var clear = function() {
    var menuElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab]');
    for (var i = 0; i < menuElements.length; i++) {
      menuElements[i].classList.remove('active');
      var id = menuElements[i].getAttribute('data-tab');
      document.getElementById(id).classList.remove('active');
    }
  }

  var change = function(e) {
    clear();
    e.target.classList.add('active');
    var id = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-tab');
    document.getElementById(id).classList.add('active');
  }

  bindAll();
}

var connectTabs = new Tabs();
```

```css
.b-tab {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: none;
}

.b-tab.active {
  display: block;
}

.b-nav-tab {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.b-nav-tab.active {
  color: #ff4200;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-tab="orange" class="b-nav-tab active">
  Orange
</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-tab="green" class="b-nav-tab">
  Green
</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-tab="blue" class="b-nav-tab">
  Blue
</a>
<div id="orange" class="b-tab active">
  Orange tab content
</div>
<div id="green" class="b-tab">
  Green tab content
</div>
<div id="blue" class="b-tab">
  Blue tab content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add this `e.preventDefault();` to your `change` function and the other way would be to replace `href="#orange"` with `href="javascript:void(0)"`. All the same with other hrefs.